# Add Jquery Events for dynamically created asp control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my project am create dynamic controls when page load based on database values. now i need to add click event for `asp:label` in `jquery` so i tried like this.

**ASP.NET**

```
        xShowVersion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top) = xTop & "px"
        xShowVersion.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "40px")
        xShowVersion.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "480px")
        xShowVersion.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute")
        xShowVersion.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "20px")
        Dim xlblShow As New Label
        xlblShow.Attributes("class") = "downlnkdetails"
        xlblShow.Text = "<h2>Show Older Versions<h2>"
        xShowVersion.Controls.Add(xlblShow)
        DivLeftVersion.Controls.Add(xShowVersion)
```

**JS**

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                  $(document).ready(function() {

                  BindButtonClickEvent();

                  });
                  function BindButtonClickEvent() {
                      $('#<%= xlblShow.ClientID %>').click(function() {

                          alert('Hai');
                          return false;
                      });
                  }   
              </script>
```

But its Show Error. How to write event for asp label or any other controls in `jquery`?

am Using **Asp.Net 2008**

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added contents you need to use below code snippet

```
$(document).on('click', '#ID' , function(e){
      alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways of doing this, is to create a jQuery event handler that'll hook up to any future elements that are added to the DOM:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "h2", function() {
   alert( "Button Clicked!" )
});
```

You can read more about this in the [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation. The 2nd parameter is a standard jQuery selector so could target by a `class`, `id`, `element type` etc.

Comment: At almost 18k rep you should know by now how to search for and vote to close as a duplicate. Delegated event handlers in jQuery have been covered more than enough times as it is, we don't need yet another answer on the topic.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Indeed I probably should have - that is my bad, sorry. There are however alternative answers for this question that are not true of the other questions (which don't feature the ASP.NET nature). I expected this answer to be an alternative and for someone to focus on a more ASP based answer using `ClientID` to be honest. I just don't know enough ASP to provide an answer of that form.